# Dynamically add new fields to page area using Plus Button - WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I need something like add new custom fields by clicking **plus** (+) button and removes newly generated custom field  when clicks **minus** (-) button as in the screen shot I have attached here.

I need this in WP page back end section ( Pages/Posts ). Is there any plug ins available?

[image]

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Show us some code.

Comment: have you tried something?? Have you googled it or not??

Comment: @RohitArora Actually I tried with the ACF plugin, but I need the add new option inside page section. I need to fetch the fields under each page in loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add fields and remove fields in back end of wordpress, then you can add page in setting and then do it like below:

```js
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.add-field {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.add-field:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.multi-fields,.multi-field{margin-top:3%;}

.textbox { 
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    width: 275px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
  }

.remove-field {
      background: rgb(202, 60, 60); /* this is a maroon */
      color: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">
    <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="add-field">+</button>        
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
          <input type="text" name="stuff[]" class="textbox">
          <button type="button" class="remove-field">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, how to display this option in WordPress back end page? I need this like a ACF plugin and we can add fields from page itself, so each page contains different custom fields and then I can loop through it to get field values under each page.

Comment: Have you added any page in the backend ? How many pages are there in backend ?Is it a custom post type ?

Comment: Yes. I have added many pages and my requirement is I need to list sub sections (Title and Content) for each page.

Comment: So is it like a setting page ? Like if you add some fields from setting page then it will reflect on all the pages that you have added ?

Comment: No. For each page I need separate fields. When we create a page, an option to add new fields also shown. And we can add multiple fields by clicking a button.

Comment: Then you can put that HTML with CSS and JS in the create page and it will be there always(As you have no mentioned anything or any code it bit difficult to make out how are you adding the page).

Answer (score 0):

> The Jquery .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection .

try this :
http://api.jquery.com/append/

> and similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it.

more information : http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 0):

You have not paste any code that you have tried so far, below answer will help you  to get an idea,

```
$('#addfield').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
        table.append('<tr><td>Name <td> <input type="text" id="Name" value="" /> </td></tr>');

});

$('#removefield').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
        table.find('input:text').last().closest('tr').remove();

});
```